# php_dir for channel "pear.php.net" is not writeable by the current user

Tags: php, pear

I am getting this error during the installation pear instal phing/phing on ubuntu 12.0.4

However I tried to chmod the php_dir , But there is no directory called php_dir

Comment: the problem was with pear install phing/phing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the reason. The problem was with the command.

All I need to do is "put sudo"

> sudo pear install phing/phing